# C# Winforms Select Where query using Datagridview Selection

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to create two datagridviews where the user will select a row and then use a SQL Inner join to populate the second datagrid view to give more information regarding.

My issue is that I get the error message Incorrect Syntax Near Device.

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.SelectedCell = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        string SerialNumber = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        Child_Refresh();
    }
}

private void Child_Refresh()
{
    string Query = "Select *" +
        "FROM Child" +
        "Inner JOIN Device ON Child.DeviceID = Device.DeviceID" +
        "WHERE Device.DeviceID = @DeviceID";

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LT-SDGFLD-1803;Initial Catalog=Test;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con);
    try
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DeviceID", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@DeviceID"].Value = Properties.Settings.Default.SelectedCell;
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ec)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ec.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: @fubo I updated the OP with my problem. I was too hasty to post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query

```
string Query = "Select *" +
    "FROM Child" +
    "Inner JOIN Device ON Child.DeviceID = Device.DeviceID" +
    "WHERE Device.DeviceID = @DeviceID";
```

result into

```
Select *FROM ChildInner JOIN Device ON Child.DeviceID = Device.DeviceIDWHERE Device.DeviceID = @DeviceID
```

and `ChildInner` or `Device.DeviceIDWHERE` are invalid syntax.

So you have to add a space between the lines

```
string Query = "Select * " +
    "FROM Child " +
    "Inner JOIN Device ON Child.DeviceID = Device.DeviceID " +
    "WHERE Device.DeviceID = @DeviceID";
```

or write it into one line for a better overview

```
string Query = "SELECT * FROM Child Inner JOIN Device ON Child.DeviceID = Device.DeviceID WHERE Device.DeviceID = @DeviceID";
```